# ubuntu 17.10 install docker with docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: ubuntu, docker

4.13.0-32-generic

and when i install docker with command like this, I got error messages which I google but can not get solution to that.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker-ce is already the newest version (17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up docker-ce (17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status docker.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for     details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─debian-style-config.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 22:12:14 CST; 9ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 16501 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16501 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 20ms

Jan 28 22:12:14 neo-Inspiron-3420 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 28 22:12:14 neo-Inspiron-3420 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When try to uninstall the docker, `sudo apt purge docker`, I got the similar error message

```
sudo apt purge docker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'docker' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up docker-ce (17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status docker.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─debian-style-config.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 22:16:05 CST; 10ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 16845 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16845 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 20ms

Jan 28 22:16:05 neo-Inspiron-3420 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 28 22:16:05 neo-Inspiron-3420 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```